# Search Only One Value in Solr MultiValued Field

Tags: solr

We have a multiValued field called "User", which is stored as a "text_en" field type.

Here is an example of a stored value, which has a 'full name' and 'email':

"User":["John Doe;John-Doe-39@email.com"]

When I perform a solr query: select?defType=edismax&q=(user:(Doe))

It's searching in the 'full name' and 'email' values.  I only want to search the 'full name' or 'email'.

I tried adding a colon (;), which separates the values, such as: select?defType=edismax&q=(user:(Doe;)) - but it appears that Solr is disregarding / filtering out this colon.

How do I search only 'full name' or 'email' in the above example?

Comment: You index them as separate fields. Don't index them in the same field if you want to query them independently.

Comment: Thanks @MatsLindh - that seems to work.  But does Solr always store multiValued fields in the same order?  Otherwise, we could have mixed-matched User field results.

Comment: Yes, Solr will keep the sequence, so you can merge the results after retrieving the documents. But you can also use three fields - two to search against and one to parse. That way you'll have a field for each use case.